# An inequality relating to a continuous and twice differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous and twice differentiable function in $[0,1]$. Please show that
$$
\int_0^1 \vert f'(x) \vert dx \leq 9\int_0^1 \vert f(x) \vert dx + \int_0^1 \vert f''(x) \vert dx 
$$

Any idea? I just couldn't find the way.

Comment: Try using the second order Taylor expansion about some point of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Which point should  we prefer here?  The point to maximize $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

proof:
 for any $\xi\in(0,1/3),\eta\in(2/3,1)$,then there exsit $\lambda\in(\xi,\eta)$,such
$$|f'(\lambda)|=\left|\dfrac{f(\eta)-f(\xi)}{\eta-\xi}\right|\le 3|f(\xi)|+3|f(\eta)|$$
so for any real number $x\in(0,1)$,have
$$|f'(x)|=|f'(\lambda)+\int_{\lambda}^{x}f''(t)dt|\le 3|f(\xi)|+3|f(\eta)|+\int_{0}^{1}|f''(t)|dt$$
so
$$\int_{2/3}^{1}\int_{0}^{1/3}|f'(x)|d\xi d\eta=\int_{2/3}^{1}\int_{0}^{1/3}\left(3|f(\xi)|+3|f(\eta)|+\int_{0}^{1}|f''(t)|dt\right)d\xi d\eta$$
$$\Longrightarrow
\dfrac{1}{9}|f'(x)|\le\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}|f(\xi)|d\xi+\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{1}|f(\eta)|d\eta+\dfrac{1}{9}\int_{0}^{1}|f''(t)|dt<\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt+\dfrac{1}{9}\int_{0}^{1}|f''(t)|dt$$
so
$$|f'(x)|\le 9\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt+\int_{0}^{1}|f''(t)|dt,x\in[0,1]$$

so
$$\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx\le 9\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx+\int_{0}^{1}|f''(x)|dx$$

Comment: Very Nice !!! (+1) :)